# retrieve the last inserted row from each user in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to make a query in mysql with php and get the last inserted row from each user i have in a database. Let me give you an example.

Suppose we have a table with 10 rows

```
ID    Message   User     Date inserted

1      lala1    chris     13/02/2010 12:13
2      lala2    john      14/02/2010 12:14
3      lala3   george    15/03/2009 12:00
4      lala4    jack      01/04/2013 11:09
5      lala5    ina       12/08/2012 15:00
6      lala6    chris     13/03/2010 12:13
7      lala7    john      14/01/2010 12:04
8      lala8   george    15/02/2009 12:00
9      lala9    jack      01/03/2013 11:09
10     lala10    ina       12/05/2012 15:00
```

I want to make a query to get the last inserted rows from chris,john and ina ordered by date. So the result should be this:

```
5      lala5    ina       12/08/2012 15:00
6      lala6    chris     13/03/2010 12:13
2      lala2    john      14/02/2010 12:14
```

then after i get the last inserted rows from these users i want to make another query to get the previous last inserted rows for these users again so the result should be:

```
10     lala10    ina       12/05/2012 15:00
1      lala1    chris     13/02/2010 12:13
7      lala7    john      14/01/2010 12:04
```

and so on...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID IN(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM myTable GROUP BY User)`

Comment: MAX(ID) will not necessarily return the latest records. We dont know that ID is auto_increment

Comment: Who makes an ID column and not have it auto_increment? haha

Comment: well maybe you want to have special ID numbers and not auto_incremented ones

Comment: Fair. So then strtotime could be the answer? I don't see why the OP doesn't just insert his date with time(), much easier to sort.

Comment: I think from his example it's safe to assume its auto inc. in which case comparing the pks would be much cleaner and faster than comparing timestamps.

Comment: Thanks for your interest guys. I want from three specific users from the table not all of them just mentioning it.

Comment: Append `limit 3` to the query.

Comment: I do not need limit because if i do not specify the users i want might give me other users as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get the last, and then the previous last, and so on, you need to use a ranking function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    Users.*,
    CASE WHEN @lst=User THEN @row:=@row+1 ELSE @row:=0 END row,
    @lst:=User
  FROM
    Users
  WHERE
    User IN ('ina','chris','john')
  ORDER BY
    User, Date_ins DESC
) s
WHERE
  row=0
```

row=0 will get the last date, row=1 the previous last, and so on...

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/036f86/5).

Comment: fthiella it seems that it works but what happens if i got 100 users at WHERE clause? Actually these 100 are in another table and i have to check which of these 100 has the latest row and then sort desc the other posts of these users by datetime...like a feed does on facebook for example with friends.

Comment: Anyway thanks i got it. This is actually the best solution for me so i am accepting it.

Comment: @stefanosn thanks :) if users are taken from another table, you could modify your where clause: `WHERE User IN (SELECT User FROM other_table)`... hope this helps!

Comment: i figured it out everything ok :) Thanks again i appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

For first part: (will give you all last insert record for all users. You can apply filter to get only 3 users)

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Users t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT User, MAX(Date_Inserted) as MaxDate
    FROM Users
    GROUP BY User
) t2 ON t1.User = t2.User AND t1.Date_Inserted = t2.MaxDate
```

you could also try replacing

```
GROUP By User
```

with

```
WHERE User IN (User_1, User_2, User_3)
```

Replace `User_1`, `User_2` and `User_3` with those 3 user names

Comment: I want from three specific users from the table not all of them just mentioning it. Does this change the query?

Comment: Please help SELECT t1.title,t1.body,t1.name,t1.category,t1.total_views,t1.datetime,t1.LANG_COUNTRY FROM MainInformation t1 INNER JOIN (Select title,body,name,category,total_views,MAX(datetime) as datetime,LANG_COUNTRY from MainInformation where name IN (' clh95lol','Abraham','alexis marie','Amore ego tu','amzie1234') t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.datetime = t2.datetime

Could not run query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.datetime = t2.datetime' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at `strtotime` found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). With it, you can convert time stamps to an integer and compare them. Also a better method would just be sorting the table by ID and limiting one.

Answer (score 1):

You must use GROUP BY in your SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT User, MAX(Date_inserted) FROM yourTable GROUP BY User
```

Comment: I want from three specific users from the table not all of them just mentioning it. Does this change the query?

Comment: You must add a WHERE clause before the GROUP BY: `WHERE User IN ('toto', 'hugues', 'ursula')`