# SQL query to get latest data blockwise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the latest data of each Block(row) base on date. but if today's date data is not available then previous dates. I have got one answer from stackoverflow below link. but query is in Mysql I need similar query in MSSQL. In my case few blocks data available today but for other blocks not available. So I need data for all blocks for which ever Block data not available that I need to take from previous dates.

[retrieve the last inserted row from each user in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368162/retrieve-the-last-inserted-row-from-each-user-in-database)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        Users.*,
        CASE WHEN @lst=User THEN @row:=@row+1 ELSE @row:=0 END row,
        @lst:=User
    FROM
        Users
    WHERE
        User IN ('ina','chris','john')
    ORDER BY
        User, Date_ins DESC
) s
WHERE
    row=0
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server equivalent would use `row_number()`:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*, row_number() over (partition by user order by date_ins desc) as seqnum
      from users u
      where u.User IN ('ina','chris','john')
     ) u
where seqnum = 1;
```